# Toggling the concealed attribute for a syntax highlight in VIM

Tags: vim

I currently have a syntax file that parses a log file, very similar to the following [this is for syslog]:

```
syn match   syslogText  /.*$/
syn match   syslogFacility  /.\{-1,}:/  nextgroup=syslogText skipwhite
syn match   syslogHost  /\S\+/  nextgroup=syslogFacility,syslogText skipwhite
syn match   syslogDate  /^.\{-}\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/  nextgroup=syslogHost skipwhite
```

I'd like to, using a map, toggle whether a given group (let's say, syslogHost) is concealed or not. Is there any way to do something like the following pseudocode:

```
map <leader>ch :syn match syslogHost conceal!
```

and thereby toggle the definition of syslogHost between:

```
syn match   syslogHost  /\S\+/  nextgroup=syslogFacility,syslogText skipwhite
```

and

```
syn match   syslogHost  /\S\+/  nextgroup=syslogFacility,syslogText skipwhite conceal
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the only way to do this is with a function:

```
map <leader>ch :call ToggleGroupConceal('sysLogHost')<CR>

function! ToggleGroupConceal(group)
    " Get the existing syntax definition
    redir => syntax_def
    exe 'silent syn list' a:group
    redir END
    " Split into multiple lines
    let lines = split(syntax_def, "\n")
    " Clear the existing syntax definitions
    exe 'syn clear' a:group
    for line in lines
            " Only parse the lines that mention the desired group
            " (so don't try to parse the "--- Syntax items ---" line)
        if line =~ a:group
                    " Get the required bits (the syntax type and the full definition)
            let matcher = a:group . '\s\+xxx\s\+\(\k\+\)\s\+\(.*\)'
            let type = substitute(line, matcher, '\1', '')
            let definition = substitute(line, matcher, '\2', '')
                    " Either add or remove 'conceal' from the definition
            if definition =~ 'conceal'
                let definition = substitute(definition, ' conceal\>', '', '')
                exe 'syn' type a:group definition
            else
                exe 'syn' type a:group definition 'conceal'
            endif
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot; this is great! The only change I made was to add a <CR> to the map, but that's hardly a significant thing (although it's about the extent of my VIM scripting abilities... :) )

Comment: Ah yes!  I tested the function and then added the mapping when I copied it into stackoverflow.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Trying roughly the same thing as OP, but this function isn't working for me using vim 8.0 and my custom log syntax. I will look further and report back, but so far it looks like the problem is parsing the output of 'syn list'. Anyone know if vim's 'syn list' has changed?

Comment: The difference is that I am using regions instead of matches to define my groups. However, the problem appears to be figuring out how ANY regex could extract the syntax group type (e.g. match or region) from the output of syn list <group>, since this doesn't include the text 'region' or 'match', only 'xxx'. @DrAl's regex captures the first keyword following the whitespace after the 'xxx'.

Comment: The output of syn list <group> doesn't generally include the syntax group type ('region' or 'match'). For 'region' type groups, there is nothing following 'xxx' except for the args. So, I guess a correct general solution to the OP's question would need to handle match and region groups separately. To identify a region type, it will be necessary to do something like capture the 'start' and 'end' args which are required for region group types.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modification to @DrAl's original one, that works with both match- and region-type syntax groups.

```
" function to toggle conceal attribute for a syntax group
function! ToggleGroupConceal(group)
    " Get the existing syntax definition for specified group
    redir => syntax_def
    exe 'silent syn list' a:group
    redir END
    " Split into multiple lines
    let lines = split(syntax_def, "\n")
    " Clear the existing syntax definitions
    exe 'syn clear' a:group
    for line in lines
        " Only parse lines that contain the desired group's definition
        " (skip "--- Syntax items ---" line and 'links to' lines)
        if line =~ a:group
            "echo 'line = ' . line
            " need to handle match and region types separately since type
            " isn't specified for regions in the syn list output like it is
            " for matches.
            let type = substitute(line, '\v' . a:group . '\s+xxx\s+(\k+)\s+(.*)', '\1', '')
            if type == 'match'
                " get args as everything after 'xxx match'
                let args = substitute(line, '\v' . a:group . '\s+xxx\s+(\k+)\s+(.*)', '\2', '')
            else
                " get args as everything after 'xxx'
                let args = substitute(line, '\v' . a:group . '\s+xxx\s+(.*)', '\1', '')
                if args =~ 'start' && args =~ 'end'
                    let type = 'region'
                endif
            endif
            "echo '    type = ' . type
            "echo '    args = ' . args
            " Either add or remove 'conceal' from the definition
            if args =~ 'conceal'
                exe 'syn' type a:group substitute(args, ' conceal', '', '')
            else
                exe 'syn' type a:group args 'conceal'
            endif
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the syntax of the file. I have a few conceal rules for my `json` files that I don't for my `javascript` files (e.g., I hide quote marks and trailing commas to make the files easier to read.) so when I want to see the whole file I just use `set syntax=javascript`. You could probably go one further and just define two sets of rules for file types (e.g., syslog.vim and syslog2.vim) where 1 inherits all from 2 and then applies conceal rules, then you could bind a key to toggle between them.