# Multiple matches for syntax highlighting in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm writing a syntax file to match a log format (basically column based; think syslog for a similar example), and I'm trying to set up a type of inheritance for columns.

I have two main goals with this.

First, I want to say that column 3 is the "component" field (let's say it's marked by a header; it could also be at a fixed position) and set the background to, say, Grey. I then want to say that component "foo" gets a foreground color of Red, and component "bar" gets a foreground color of Green, but they should inherit the background color of the "component" column. In this case, the field should really have two syntax matches; this also makes it easy to conceal the entire column (a la [Toggling the concealed attribute for a syntax highlight in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853631/toggling-the-concealed-attribute-for-a-syntax-highlight-in-vim))

Second, there's a field for levels; I want to set the background of the entire line for a critical level message to Red, but the foreground should be continue to be set via the normal highlighting (component, source, etc; I left off most of the other requirements).

From what I can see in the vim documentation, this doesn't seem possible. Am I missing something? Alternatively, can anyone suggest a good workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't (yet). For each character, Vim only uses one particular highlight group, determined by the last, "most inner" non-transparent syntax group match.

To work around this, you need to define a combined highlight group and corresponding `:syntax` commands. Some syntaxes (e.g. `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`, and various Wiki formats) use that for combining bold, italic and underline, but it gets tedious and repetitive after that.

There's a [patch proposed](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/e58820848647ffec/0bb8fefb0d2133ea#0bb8fefb0d2133ea) that would add a `combine` modifier for `:syntax` commands; it's in Bram's Todo list.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I can probably script the generation of all the combinations, rather than write them out myself... any suggestions for how I can achieve the conceal effect, though? I could always have some special values that iterate over all of the possible types, but I was hoping this way to let the user look at synID and know what to conceal.

Comment: That linked conceal solution looks like a nice hack when used on an external syntax, but inside your own syntax (especially if you have to script the definitions, anyway), I would rather use a config variable that determines which syntax group(s) get the `conceal` attribute. To change, you then have to change the variable, and `:syntax on` again.

Comment: Right now, I have maps for concealing common columns, so it could work either way; I had this idea, however, of letting the user call ConcealCurrentGroup() and have it automatically hide whatever column the cursor was on. Oh well.