# extract regex used to define syntax object in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to access the regex definition of a syntax object stored in vim? I would prefer not having to parse syntax files or the output off for instance

```
:syntax list vimFunc

--- Syntax items ---
vimFunc        xxx match /\%(\%([sSgGbBwWtTlL]:\|<[sS][iI][dD]>\)\=\%([a-zA- Z0-9_.]\+\.\)*\I[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*\)\ze\s*(/  contains=vimFuncName,vimUserFunc,vimExecute 
               links to vimError
```

Comment: What do you need the regex for? To write your own (similar) syntax, or really programmatically to extend it?

Comment: I actually want to use them as aliases together with the  `:vimgrep` command.

Answer (score 0):

But that **is** the regex used to define syntax group.

To get to the correct syntax file you only need to look into `:scriptnames` since `:syntax list <group>` will only work for the groups in the syntax of the current file type.  You get the file type with `set ft?` (e.g. `filetype=vim`) and then search for that file type in `:scriptnames` with a `/syntax/` prefix (which turns to be `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim` on my system).

Using that technique I can find that the line defining the regex match is:

```
syn match vimFunc       "\%(\%([sSgGbBwWtTlL]:\|<[sS][iI][dD]>\)\=\%([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\.\)*\I[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*\)\ze\s*("      contains=vimFuncName,vimUserFunc,vimExecute
```

Which (discounting the quotes) is the same as the output of `:syntax list vimFunc`.

---

Shameless beta stack exchange website marketing: we have [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) especially for Vim questions.

Comment: Hm, using vim 8, the syntax group type (e.g. match or region) appears to be replaced with 'xxx' in the output of syn list <group>. @grochmal, any ideas why? Also, see my related comment in other therad here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853631/toggling-the-concealed-attribute-for-a-syntax-highlight-in-vim

Comment: Note that this answer is only strictly true for 'match' type syntax groups. For region type syntax groups, 'syn match' only outputs 'xxx', followed by the args provided in the original 'syn region' command. (Anyone know why this is? Is there another way to generically and programatically determine the syntax group type?)